# Why is this bash script read line code giving me errors?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, scripting, error-handling

Why is this bash script read line code giving me errors?

```
read -p "Does this require cropping? (y/n)? " answer
case ${answer:0:1} in
    y|Y )
mkdir cropped; for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -filter:v "crop=1900:1080:-20:0" cropped/"${i%.*}.mp4"; rm -r *.mp4; cd cropped; cp -r *.mp4 ../
    ;;
    * )
mkdir no
    ;;
esac
```

When I give an answer, I get this back from terminal:

```
Does this require cropping? (y/n)? n
/usr/local/bin/prep: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `;;'
/usr/local/bin/prep: line 17: `    ;;'
```

However, it works perfectly fine if my executed (YES) answer code is changed something like, rather than the whole `mkdir cropped; for i in *.mp4...`:

```
mkdir yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `done` on your `for` loop, so the `no )` and stuff is part of the loop.

Comment: Ohhhh.. you mean after `*.mp4 ../` so it should be `*.mp4 ../ done` ?

Comment: seems to be missing `; done` ... got it, thanks!